# Image (Error) Image.reduceResolution: The input to reduceResolution does not have a valid default projection. Use setDefaultProjection() first

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat, resampling, reducers

I would like to aggregate the 30m images to 990m on average through `reduceResolution`, but he shows me to add the default coordinate system, but I have already added it and this still happens.

Below is my GEE code, link to he code [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/a3a2e873ed8a4f410c31ca0cd8258717?accept_repo=users%2Fsofiaermida%2Flandsat_smw_lst).

```js
function resample_990(image) {
    var resample_image = image.reproject({
        crs: 'EPSG:4326',
        scale: 990
    }).reduceResolution({
        reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
        maxPixels: 1024
    }) return resample_image
}
```

and the error:
`Image (Error) Image.reduceResolution: The input to reduceResolution does not have a valid default projection. Use setDefaultProjection() first`

Comment: Kindly edit the post and add the code, need not mention in the comments.